# Redirection to a strange file descriptor no

Tags: ksh

I came across a working ksh script [interactive] today, where I saw the below statement.

```
printf "Enter the release no. : " >&5
```

I wonder the use of `>&5` when the author could have as well use nothing or say `>&1`.

Can someone shed some light on this point ?

Thanks in advance

--
Benil

Comment: show more of that script. he may have file descriptor 5 declared some where else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He probably has remapped the file descriptors or does use the file descriptor 5 for something special

e.g. to only temporarily redirect errors to `/dev/null`

```
#errors produced here go to stderr
....
#now save stderr to fd 5
exec 5>&2
#redirect to /dev/null
exec 2>/dev/null
...
# do stuff which errors are discarded
......
# restore stderr from fd 5
exec 2>&5
```

So check more of the script what it does before

Comment: +1 for a helpful, real-world example. Redirecting file descriptors is one of those features that can perform magic if you take the time to learn the nuances.

Comment: Jitter, you are right. The author has defined it earlier and he mapped stdout to descriptor 5 first and then to a log file. That way standard cmds' o/p will go to logfiles and occasionally to print something on screen he used desc.5 
Thanks a lot. 
--
Benil